# Python - How to compare list with dictionary by keys and return values - put then into a list

Tags: python, list

I have an example:

```
birthday_persons = ['1966-06-26T11:50:25.558Z', '1949-10-09T00:25:51.304Z']

dates_ids = {'1966-06-26T11:50:25.558Z': 1, '1949-10-09T00:25:51.304Z': 2, '1992-11-21T06:28:32.563Z': 3}
```

Dict key is a date of birth, and dict value is an id number.

I need to compare list and a dict keys and return dict.value (id) if element from list is equal.

How can I do that?

Comment: use list comprehension, ``[dates_ids[x] for x in birthday_persons if dates_ids.get(x)]``

Comment: Thank you, that's great!

Answer (score 0):

its basically that:

```
for birthday_person in birthday_persons:
    if birthday_person in dates_ids:
        value = dates_ids.get(birthday_person)
        print(value)
```

you check if the person exists in the dict and then get the value

Comment: Or use a list comprehension like mentioned form @Sushanth

Answer (score 0):

```
for bday in birthday_persons:
  if bday in dates_ids.keys():
    return dates_ids[bday]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use for loop to archive this

```py
for bday in birthday_persons:
    print(dates_ids[bday])
```